# ZeroMQ on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, zeromq, netmq

I've been developing an app for Windows Phone 8.1 and i wanted to use ZeroMQ for the communication with the server. I've used ZMQ before and it has always worked after some trying but i just coulnd't get it to work with WP8.1. I already tried to use NetMQ but i get the error "the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework" when trying to install it via NuGet, the same Problem with clrzmq4 and Castle.ZMQ  Is there any possibility out there to get ZeroMQ running on WP8.1? I'm thankful for your help.

Comment: It's just a shot in the dark, but what happens if you change platform to only "x86" or "ARM" instead of "Any CPU" (right-click in solution explorer, then "Properties", [screenshot](http://www.schaikweb.net/dotnetbyexample/5e30c614e89e_1291C/image.png))? Maybe those packages are just pre-compiled for one platform...

Comment: Ok i tried that i still get the same error: "Install-Package : Could not install package 'AsyncIO 0.1.17.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author." I guess i'll just drop that and move on to develop the same app for android instead of Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/issues/105), ZeroMQ is not compatible with Windows Phone, since this doesn't support the .NET sockets library.

I guess you'll have to use an alternative or build your own then...